# Prevent OpenCV writing error/warning log to commandline

Tags: java, opencv

I'm using OpenCV 3.1.0 Java libraries to capture and display a webcam however OpenCV is continually printing warnings/errors to the commandline e.g.

> Corrupt JPEG data: 2 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd5

Is there a Java library call I can use to stop this from happening? I know I can use `2&>/dev/nell` on the commandline but I'm currently running through IDE so a method call at application start-up would be better